# Can we use an infinitive clause with no object in order to specify a purpose?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, infinitive-clauses

Even if it is not a common way, it seems that we can use an infinitive clause with no object for a purpose statement.

We talked here before about the accuracy of the question

> Who did you find to study **with**?

and everyone agreed with the idea that "to study with" is an adverbial relative clause there stating a purpose. Then we can see that infinitive clauses don't have to be attached to nouns.

The other example;

> She is hard to study **with**, because, she is really lazy.

Again, "to study with" doesn't need any noun for its own preposition "with".

Let's come to the main point now.

These details make the following sentences *grammatically*/*linguistically* correct.

> To study with, I found someone who is one of the most successful students at the university.(Why did you find him? To study with.)

According to some people, we **have to** say:

> To study with *him*, I found someone who is one of the most successful students at the university.

But they don't have any evidence for it.

We don't say:

> "She is hard to study with **her**." or "Who did you find to study with **him**?"

I believe that in those kinds contexts, we don't need to use a pronoun because using it is more confusing..

What do you think?

If you think that we have to use a pronoun, what is your evidence/reason?

Comment: When you have words like **hard** or **difficult** or **easy** and so forth, it colors the meaning of the infinitive clause.  *It is hard to do* means "To do it is difficult".  The infinitive clause does not refer to purpose there but to the action per se.  You are predicating something about the action. *To get there, you must turn left at the next street*. There the infinitive clause expresses purpose.

Comment: You are making some false assertions here. "To study with, I found someone..." is not idiomatic.  *To dance with, I found someone.* is not idiomatic.

Comment: *To study with him, I found someone who is one of the most successful students at the university.*  does not make clear sense, at least it does not have the meaning you intend.  It would be understood to mean that finding that most successful student enabled you to study with someone else.

Comment: What about "To study together, I found someone..." ? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: That's the same as *To dance with, I found someone*, unidiomatic.

Comment: When the infinitive clause is an object complement you cannot begin the sentence with the infinitive clause.

Comment: you are right, I am just trying to make it out of an object complement. 
So let's say
"To study, I found someone..."
"To dance by morning, I found someone..." @Tᴚoɯɐuo Still wrong?

Comment: Neither is idiomatic.  I don't know what *to dance by morning* even means, and your **study** example seems just another object complement in the wrong position, with the person being the topic of your study, not a comrade engaged in study with you.

Comment: I don't why they have to be complements of something? 
I want to use them in order to state a purpose.
Why did you find someone at the party?
In order to dance until the morning/by the morning(not sure)
Why did you find someone?
In order to study at math.
Why are they impossible? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: In **To study I found someone** the infinitive clause, if it is intended to refer to a goal or purpose, is an *inadequate* or *insufficient* statement of the intended purpose.  It is not clearly a purpose. Why is a "someone" needed when all you wish to do is study? You would need to flesh-out the infinitive clause more:   *To study with an insightful and well-informed companion, I began my search for a study partner not in the tavern or in the video game arcade but in the library.*

Comment: The additional information in both clauses guides the parsing so that the infinitive clause is understood to be a stated purpose.  You're at the syntax/semantics membrane.

Comment: I've just totally understood you. Saying "To study at physics, I found someone." doesn't explain the connection between studying at physics and finding that person. There is interrupted information there. Got it. However, saying "I found someone to study at physics with" explains what I am going to do with that person. @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: In "Who did you find [to study with]? there's nothing adverbial about the bracketed clause -- it is simply a modifier of 'who', where the meaning is "Did you find x, you could study with x". It doesn't mean "did you find 'x' in order that that you could study with 'x.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not a member of the forum when this issue was originally discussed, so forgive me if anything I say simply repeats what has been said. I would also like to say that I am not a grammar expert, so I am happy to have my conclusions corrected.

> Who did you find to study with?

I would have thought that this is a shortened version of:

> Who did you find to study with you?

If this is so, then the original sentence only appears not to have a noun or pronoun associated with the infinitive because the second "you" has been elided, although it is still understood to be there.

> To study with, I found someone who is one of the most successful students at the university.

This sentence is not grammatical. To retain the intended meaning you could say:

> I found someone to study with who is one of the most successful students at the university.

This next sentence is problematic. Taken literally, it mentions three different people, i.e. him, I and someone. Also, taken literally, you are not necessarily studying with the other two people, all you have done is find two people to study with each other.

> To study with him, I found someone who is one of the most successful students at the university.

If you change "him" to "me" this sentence would make more sense.

> To study with me, I found someone who is one of the most successful students at the university.

But even this sentence could be improved if it was changed to:

> I found someone to study with me who is one of the most successful students at the university.

You were correct when you said that we cannot say:

> "She is hard to study with her."

but we can say:

> She is hard to study with.

which is a sentence that does not require a noun to complement the infinitive. You were also correct in saying that we should say:

> "Who did you find to study with him?"

but only because "Who" should be "Whom", although many people would be happy with the sentence without this correction. However, once again this sentence implies that you are finding someone to study with a third person. It makes no sense if it is meant to ask if you have found someone to study with you.